# Text-overflow not working on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2013

I'm coding some CSS within SharePoint 365, and here I'm trying to do this: 
https://codepen.io/srekoble/pen/EgmyxV

I have it working perfectly in Chrome, and even on the codepen version. However when it gets applied to my live edition, it simply doesnt hide the text when the max-width limit is reached.

Here is my own code.

```
td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2 {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 50px;
}
```

Here is the result:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kexbz.png)

As it appears, the CSS rule does not seem to apply on IE, and does not limit the text to display.

Here is the HTML for the block.

```
<td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2" role="gridcell" style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 20px;"><a class="ms-listlink" onclick="EditLink2(this,21);return false;" onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="https://rosendahldesigngroup.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId=%7BA8CAC965%2D8031%2D43A4%2DAD23%2D0DD14BE6012D%7D&amp;ID=116&amp;ContentTypeID=0x010200283C7299F6299B4D99C5E4ACE117C0C1" target="_self">BFA arr. HHX innovation og designlinie i Lyngby</a><span class="ms-newdocument-iconouter"><img title="new" class="ms-newdocument-icon" alt="new" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=44"></span></td>
```

Comment: The `ms-cellstyle` class does not exist in the `td` element you've quoted for your HTML block, so the styles you've given won't be applied.

Comment: Ill check the HTML, but it does appear, because the code works perfectly on Chrome and every other browser. Now, look at this. If I use the DEV tool from IE, I can actually make it work on the specific element by using inline styling. Imgur here: http://imgur.com/a/MO5UV

Comment: I'd expect `overflow` not to be applicable to table cells. Wrap your content in a `div` or something inside the `td` and apply the styles to that instead. There's alot of stuff that doesn't work with tables as you'd expect it to when coming from regular CSS container styling.

Comment: It's not possible to access that specific snippet content on SharePoint. This has to be a CSS solution somehow. I can wrap a DIV around the snippet, thats about it.

Comment: Now that you've updated the HTML, it looks like you've got the styles applying directly to the `td` element. This will not work in any browser ([proof here in jsfiddle, cut+pasted from your example](https://jsfiddle.net/tu5ey66q)). However, if I modify the example to add an extra `div` element inside the `td` and apply the styles to that, then it works in all browsers ([modified jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tu5ey66q/1/)).

Comment: I can't access the td, it's restricted. The only thing I can do is make a div around the snippet :(